# How can I rewrite/reformat an array?

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I am developing an API but I am having a problem connecting it to a payment platform, because they ask for the preference with the following format:

```
'items' => [
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'title' => 'Product 1',
            'description' => 'Some description',
            'picture_url' => 'img.png',
            'quantity' => 1,
            'currency_id' => 'USD',
            'unit_price' => 20
        ],

        [
            'id' => 2,
            'title' => 'Product 2',
            'description' => 'Some description',
            'picture_url' => 'img.png',
            'quantity' => 1,
            'currency_id' => 'USD',
            'unit_price' => 25
        ]
    ]
```

but I am receiving my data from my items in the cart like this:

```
 'items' => json_encode(new CartItemCollection($items))
```

And that collection (my collection CartItemCollection) have this format:

```
 {
   "Items":[
              {
                "productID":1,
                "inventoryID":1,
                "name":"Product 1",
                "Quantity":1,
                "price":20,
                "image":"img.png"
              },

              {
                "productID":2,
                "inventoryID":1,
                "name":"Product2 "
                "Quantity":1,
                "price":25,
                "image":"img.png"
               }
            ],
        "items_count":2,
        "products_count":2
    }
```

So I'm sending (which is wrong):

```
'items' => "Items":[
              {
                "productID":1,
                "inventoryID":1,
                "name":"Product 1",
                "Quantity":1,
                "price":20,
                "image":"img.png"
              },

              {
                "productID":2,
                "inventoryID":1,
                "name":"Product2 "
                "Quantity":1,
                "price":25,
                "image":"img.png"
               }
            ],
        "items_count":2,
        "products_count":2
```

How can I rewrite or re format that: `json_encode(new CartItemCollection($items))` to get the rigth array?

I kind of need to do this:

foreach (Items) in my collection, do: ProductID (mine) rewrite as id (plataform), Quantity (mine) rewrite as quantity (plataform), price (mine) rewrite as unit_price (plataforms) etc etc..

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What does CartItemCollection look like?

Comment: And what you get in that items before passing it to that class?

Comment: @ChristoffX My collection looks like I posted it, I just edit the question to be more specific, but is the : "Items":[{...

Comment: @ZeljkoMiloradovic my $items are just an array of items in the cart, but those items has no price (or at least not as the plataform expects)

Comment: The thing is that I need to reformat the whole collection, I was thinking maybe with a foreach, and asign new keys and values, like, manually, but I really dont know how can I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/eloquent-resources#adding-meta-data), a different approach could be define another Collection Resource class to customise the response.

```
return new CustomCartItemCollection($items);
```

Inside the CustomCarItemCollection.php class:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class CustomCarItemCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    public $collects = 'App\Http\Resources\Item';

    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'items' => $this->collection,
        ];
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Item extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->ProductID,
            'quantity' => $this->Quantity,
            'unit_price' => $this->Price,
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the code it seems like you are using Eloquent API resources for your `CartItem` model.

If that's correct you shouldn't use json_encode, as it would convert your object to a string, but you can try to call directly the `toArray` method on the `CartItemCollection`:

```php
'items' => (new CartItemCollection($items))->toArray()['Items']
```

This code might need a bit of tweaking as you didn't post the `CartItemCollection`'s class code as well as other relevant code you use to generate the structure of the output you are now getting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I'd just edit the original question to be a bit specific, and what part do you need me to post about CartItemCollection? 
And yes, I'm using Eloquent ahah sorry didnt mentioned that

Comment: You can try the code as it might be working anyways, but to be sure you could as well post the `CartItemCollection` and `CartItemResource` classes